# Display List in input text

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to display a list when user writes a X symbol in input text.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTpRt.png):

[image]

[Example Action Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHlDx.gif):

[image]

Comment: While I've edited the question to bring the images in-line with the question, this question is - as currently written - *too broad*, you need to post your "*[mcve]*" code, explain precisely what you want to happen, explain what's currently happening and how your current code is failing your expectation. Please read the "*[ask]*" guidance.

Comment: If you seek quality answers you should have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This falls into the topic of Suggestions and Autocomplete, for which there are many free and commercial pre-existing solutions for.
https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+suggestions ,

https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+autocomplete

Comment: I honestly use DevExpress combo boxes in large data mode and show results after two characters have been entered when I do things like this.  But this commercial control set wasn't my choice nor do i endorse any commercial control.  Jquery UI has autocomplete for free, and there are probably other free jquery plugins, or other commercial solutions (such as telerik).
 https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxDataEditorsDemos/Editors/LargeDataComboBox

Answer (score -1):

You could do an ajax request on keyup event to search the database for matches based on the characters in the input field, and then display the results in a list under your input field.

Comment: Couldn't care less about +1 or -1 votes, I'm only trying to help based on my limited experience. But is there a way to see  the motivation for a downvote? Maybe I could learn something from the reason my reply was so foolish.

Comment: Could just be for answering the question at all, if it's too broad and generic, I suppose?  If I recall correctly, you need a higher number of points to downvote, so then if that is true, it probably wasn't the person who posted the question.  But it also could be that your "answer" might be better as a "comment".  But I'm guessing it's the prior.